# VBA Insert MS Access Form to Separate Access DB

Tags: vba, ms-access

At work I have two MS Access files that need to stay separate. The first file is a form/DB combo that creates a DB entry and also uses VBA code to auto-populate 5 separate PDFs. The second file is a database that contains mostly similar but different info from the first one and is meant for different people. Therefore, these Access files cannot be combined into one. With that being said, my goal is to make the first form update the database of the second file without having to manually input the data for a second time.

```
        Dim SPCdbs As Database
        Set SPCdbs = OpenDatabase("SPC_Database.accdb")
        SPCdbs.Execute "INSERT INTO [*All Student*] (Code, SSN, [Last Name], [First Name], [Middle Name], Rank) VALUES (6, 888888888, ''Tester'', ''tester'', ''NMI'', 10)"
        SPCdbs.Close
```

The query I have listed there isn't a huge priority at the moment as I'm going to fill in the static pieces with variables that are found earlier in the code, but I'm happy for any advice that can be given.

The database location suggests that the files are in the same location but in the actual execution they'll be in different locations. I currently have copies of both files in the same folder for testing purposes only.

Comment: Have the table in 2nd database linked from the 1st one. You will not need to update anything.

Comment: You should _split_ both databases - to obtain two frontends and _one_ shared backend. The latter will hold all tables and nothing else.

Comment: I'll look into these ideas. I'm trying to make minimal amount of "noticeable" changes to the people working with these access files. Are these suggestions because they're easier? Or because what I'm attempting doesn't work? I'm okay with doing whatever gets the job done, I just don't want to interrupt other work centers' processes.

Comment: Because what you propose is a formula for disaster. At some point, something will cause data to get 'out of sync' and the cleanup could be a nightmare. Follow one of the two suggestions in comments. I would go further and suggest a single frontend with code that 'knows' the user and presents appropriate data and forms/reports.

Comment: Got wrapped up in the project and forgot to update post. I'm taking all of your advice and just revamping the entire thing to properly meet everyone's needs. Probably a lot more work than I intended but it'll go better. Thanks for the help!